# Errors while exporting to .xls using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xls

I've asked a similar question previously but Ive been told my question is just me being lazy so let me rephrase.

Ive been using a PHP class script to enable me to export my SQL data to a .xls file but the resultant excel file doesnt display any values and no error is being displayed on the webpage itself.

The class file Im using is documented in the link below:

http://web.burza.hr/blog/php-class-for-exporting-data-in-multiple-worksheets-excel-xml/

And Ive incorporated it in my site as follows

```
$dbase->loadextraClass('excel.xml');

$excel = new excel_xml();

$header_style = array(
                        'bold'       => 1,
                        'size'       => '14',
                        'color'      => '#000000',
                        'bgcolor'    => '#ffffff'
                    );

$excel->add_style('header',$header_style);


if(isset($_POST['fec_save']))
{
    if($_POST['reporttype']=='films')
    {

        $films = $dbase->runquery("SELECT datetime,title,country_of_origin,language,runningtime,(SELECT name FROM fec_client WHERE filmid = fec_film.filmid) AS client, (SELECT rating_decision FROM fec_rating_report WHERE filmid = fec_film.filmid) AS rating FROM fec_film WHERE datetime >= '".strtotime($_POST['fromdate'])."' AND datetime <= '".strtotime($_POST['todate'])."'",'multiple');

        $filmcount = $dbase->getcount($films);

        //continue with excel buildup
        $columns = array('Date','Title','Origin','Language','Minutes','Client','Rating');
        $excel->add_row($columns,'header');

        for($i=1; $i<=$filmcount; $i++)
        {
            $film = $dbase->fetcharray($films);

            $excel->add_row($film['datetime'],$film['title'],$film['country_of_origin'],$film['language'],$film['runningtime'],$film['client'],$film['rating']);
        }

        $excel->create_worksheet('From_'.str_replace(' ','',$_POST['fromdate']).'_to'.str_replace(' ','',$_POST['todate']));

        $xml = $excel->generate();
        $excel->download('FilmsClassified_from_'.str_replace(' ','',$_POST['fromdate']).'_to'.str_replace(' ','',$_POST['todate']));
    }

}
```

I would like some assistance as to what I maybe doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What have you done to debug the issue so far?

Comment: The problem is that people are not going to want to start [debugging that 3rd party class](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/172936)... You'll have to narrow down the problem... Try creating minimal examples and when you hit a wall then you can be more specific about what part exactly is giving you problems...

Comment: As I have stated in the question its difficult to narrow down the problem since no error messages are being displayed either in the newly created .xls file or the creating webpage.

Comment: @Paul - the $_POST['fec_save'] is set

Comment: Also the 3rd party class works fine with other guys using it. So it must be within my code.

Comment: 1. How are you sure? 2. Do you have error message turned on?

Comment: Well the library you're using doesn't actually create an xls file, at least it doesn't create a BIFF file, but a format used by Excel 2003 called SpreadsheetML. Earlier versions of Excel will have problems opening this file, while the latest issue a warning that it isn't a valid xls file

Comment: What is created in the file? Open it in a text editor to see.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the pointer. Will revise the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Too long to post as a comment:

```
$xml = $excel->generate();
```

creates all the xml file content as a string and stores it in $xml
while

```
$excel->create_worksheet('From_'.str_replace(' ','',$_POST['fromdate']).'_to'.str_replace(' ','',$_POST['todate']));
```

creates the xml and directs it to output, with appropriate headers for downloading.

So you're not using the class correctly, as that's unnecessary duplication of work.